# Image div height jump in slideshow

Tags: html, jquery, css

I made a image slideshow in jquery. But when first image change to second height of the div jumps to lower value. And when last image change to first height jump back to original size. And I don't understand why.
Here is a gif animation of what happened.

[image: Jump animation]

And my code (in this snippet height also jump).

```js
function swapBanners(){
      var $active = $('#ifdesignbanners .active');
      var $next = ($('#ifdesignbanners .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#ifdesignbanners .active').next() : $('#ifdesignbanners img:first');
      $active.fadeOut(function(){
      $active.removeClass('active');
      $next.fadeIn().addClass('active');
      });
}
 
$(document).ready(function(){
      // Run our swapImages() function every 2secs
      setInterval('swapBanners()', 2000);
})
```

```css
#design_awards img {
  height: 150px;
}
#ifdesignbanners img {
  display: none;
}
#ifdesignbanners img.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col text-center" id="design_awards">
  <div class="d-inline-block" id="ifdesignbanners">
    <img class="active" src="https://competition.adesignaward.com/images/logo-of-a-design-award.png" alt="Награды">
    <img src="https://wdo.org/wp-content/uploads/iF_DesignAward2023_red.png " alt="Награды">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/Logo_iF_DESIGN_AWARD_2021.png " alt="Награды">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <div class="row gx-2 gy-3 gx-md-4">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row gx-0 gy-3 gy-md-4 row-cols-1">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="card border-0 ratio ratio-4x3">
                        <img class="img-fluid card-img w-100 d-block" src="https://klinika-milano.ru/images/Beautylizer.JPG">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column justify-content-center justify-content-lg-end project_card">
                                <div class="project_text">
                                    <h5 class="my-0">Text</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code you posted runs pretty fine. Nothing jumps. Inspect element (those images) and make some that indeed their `height` CSS rule is respected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I made it work.
Just replace `display:block` to `display:inline-block`.

CSS:

```
#design_awards img {
  height: 150px;
}
#ifdesignbanners img {
  display: none;
}
#ifdesignbanners img.active {
  display: block;
}
```